# Database Based Templating System

Tags: php, mysql, template-engine

As a part of a script I'm writing I would like to add a templating system where the variables are derived from a database table like this:

```
id int auto_increment primary key, 
name varchar(200) not null, 
value float(6,2) not null
```

My problems are:

1- I am not able to find a way that makes it user-friendly to display those variables when editing a page & I don't know how many variables there would be so I cannot add all-in-one form.

2- I don't know how the variable should be saved to the database (I'm looking to save a reference of the variable not its value so when it's updated on the table, all pages that uses it will have the new value) ... but using the variable number doesn't seem to be clear on what it holds when someone first looks into the page while editing.

3- Should I use something like **preg_replace** to replace those variables or is there a better method to do that?

Comment: 3: No, you certainly shouldn't use a regex to perform a plain string replacement.

Comment: Your second point doesn't quite make sense. If the row in that table with ID 15 has a value of 3,14 (and really, change float(6, 2)  to decimal(6, 2)), then everywhere  where you select row 15 and show its value on a page, it will be 3,14. If you then update its value, all pages that request that value will show the new value.

Comment: @ThiefMaster what's the better way to do this? I have further explained my requirements in the comments below as I have noticed my question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you are seeking a way to extract column definitions from your database to build a web form regarding to the fields defined in a database table? if this is the case, you can obtain the structure easily with

```
SHOW COLUMNS 
FROM database-table
```

Even better would be to use the *information_schema* database (available since MySQL 5.x), because you wont have to parse anything from it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  table_name = "database-table"
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster: you are right. I've replaced it. Actually i do not know, why i put LIKE there ... maybe it was just a too hard workday today ;)

Comment: As I read it he wants to dynamically create a form for CRUD operations on that table.

Comment: It's not about creating a form, it's more like templates of variables let's say I have added a new entry in the aforementioned table, And in the content table I have written something like 'The current gold prices is {GOLD_PRICE}' I'm looking for a nice way to present these variables to editors in the back-end ... and a way to replace these variables for the front-end use.